# Displaying text, using different formats, using two separate variables on the same line in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

In my en.yml. I have the following:

```
user:
  first: "First"
  last: "Last"
```

In my view, I have the following:

```
<% = "t('user.first') t('user.last')" %>
```

I want user.last to be bold, underlined and a larger font. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `<span>` where you add a class that has font weight setup to bold

```
<%= "t('user.first')" %><span class="text-special"><%= t('user.last')" %></span>
```

In your CSS file you add

```css
.text-special {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Or you can add a `<span>` where you add a style directly in it

```
<%= "t('user.first')" %><span style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration: underline; font-size:14px;"><%= t('user.last')" %></span>
```